# Specific filter on the set using Python

Tags: optimization, modeling, python, open-source

I'm trying to write an optimization model using an open-source solver's Python API. I'm new to use Python. The model objective function is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(f_{k}+c_{0, j}^{k}\right) x_{0, j}^{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j \in\{0, \ldots, n\} \backslash\{i\}} c_{i j}^{k} x_{i j}^{k}
\end{equation}

where $(i, j, k)$ are indices, $x$ is a variable and $c,f$ are given parameters. In the second term of the objective function, there is a specific filter on the $j$ index. Doing this filter using C++/Java is easy. I was wondering, how can I do that in Python?

The snippet Python code is:

```
minimize (sum(c(k,i,j)*x[k][i][j] for k in range(K) for i in range(n) for j in range(n)))
```

Comment: In your math, you have i going from 1 to n and j going from 0 to n, but in your code, you have both going from 0 to n-1. What behavior is intended?

Comment: @Acccumulation, thanks so much for your attention. As I mentioned, this was The snippet code. I will try to fix it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy:

```
minimize (sum(c(k,i,j)*x[k][i][j] for k in range(K) for i in range(n) for j in range(n) if j != i))
```

But note that your sums start from indices $1$ and end at $n$, while `range(n)` gives you $0$ to $n-1$.